# Issues renaming files using bash script with input from .txt file with find -exec rename command

Tags: bash, find, rename

**Update 01/12/2022**

With triplee's helpful suggestions, I resolved it to take both files & directories by adding a comma in between f and d, the final code now looks like this:

```
while read -r old new; 
   do echo "replacing ${old} by ${new}" >&2 
   find '/path/to/dir' -depth -type d,f -name "$old" -exec rename 
   "s/${old}/${new}/" {} ';' 
done <input.txt
```

Thank you!

---

**Original request:**

I am trying to rename a list of files (from `$old` to `$new`), all present in `$homedir` or in subdirectories in `$homedir`.

In the command line this line works to rename files in the subfolders:
`find ${homedir}/ -name ${old} -exec rename "s/${old}/${new}/" */${old} ';'`

However, when I want to implement this line in a simple bash script getting the `$old` and `$new` filenames from `input.txt`, it doesn't work anymore...

`input.txt` looks like this:

```
name_old name_new
name_old2 name_new2
etc...
```

the script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
homedir='/path/to/dir'

cat input.txt | while read old new; 
do
    echo 'replacing' ${old} 'by' ${new}
    find ${homedir}/ -name ${old} -exec rename "s/${old}/${new}/" */${old} ';'
done
```

After running the script, the text line from echo with `$old` and `$new` filenames being replaced is printed for the entire loop, but no files are renamed. No error is printed either. What am I missing? Your help would be greatly appreaciated!

I checked whether the `$old` and `$new` variables were correctly passed to the `find -exec rename` command, but because they are printed by `echo` that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Could it be that `old` contains  a space?  Also, the unquoted `*/${old}` means that the wildcard is evaluated before `find` is invoked. Aside from this, I would for debugging prefix the `rename` by an echo, to see what commands would be executed. Also it could be a good idea to do a `set -x` in your script.

Comment: BTW, wouldn't it be easier to use instead of the `-exec` part a `-execdir mv "$old" "$new" \:`?

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the tag _exec_, because the question is not related to the `exec` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an `echo`, like `-exec echo rename ...`, you'll see what actually gets executed. I'd say that both the path to `$old` is wrong (you're not using the result of `find` in the `-exec` clause), and `*/$old` isn't quoted and might be expanded by the shell before `find` ever gets to see it.

You're also having most other expansions unquoted, which can lead to all sorts of trouble.

You could do it in pure Bash (drop `echo` when output looks good):

```bash
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/"$old"; do echo mv "$f" "${f/%*/$new}"; done
```

Or with `rename` directly, though this would run into trouble if too many files match (drop `-n` when output looks good):

```bash
rename -n "s/$old\$/$new/" **/"$old"
```

Or with GNU find, using `-execdir` to run in the same directory as the matching file (drop `echo` when output looks good):

```bash
find -type f -name "$old" -execdir echo mv "$old" "$new" \;
```

And finally, a version with `find` that spawns just a single subshell (drop `echo` when output looks right):

```bash
find -type f -name "$old" -exec bash -c '
    new=$1
    shift
    for f; do
        echo mv "$f" "${f/%*/$new}"
    done
' bash "$new" {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `rename` should be the file itself, not `*/${old}`. You also have a number of quoting errors, and a [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)).

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r old new; 
do
    echo "replacing ${old} by ${new}" >&2
    find /path/to/dir -name "$old" -exec rename "s/${old}/${new}/" {} ';'
done <input.txt
```

Running `find` multiple times on the same directory is hugely inefficient, though. Probably a better solution is to find all files in one go, and abort if it's not one of the files on the list.

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec sh -c '
    for f in "$@"; do
       awk -v f="$f" "f==\$1 { print \"s/\" \$1 \"/\" \$2 \"/\" }" "$0" |
       xargs -I _ -r rename _ "$f"
    done' input.txt {} +
```

(Untested; probably try with `echo` before you run this live.)

Comment: Thanks! The bottom (efficient) version gives an error about -exec supporting only one instance of {}

The top one works for the files but not the directories I have in the list. Is it possible to make this work for directories too in the same command? As it's not specified (-d / -f) now, I hoped it would take all types.

Comment: Ah, I see, I updated with hopefully a sensible fix for the second one. Sorry for the bug. To also include directories, try `\( -type f -o -type d \)` but then you probably also want `-d` for a depth-first traversal.